# How would you print number 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,18,19,20,21,22,23,24 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, if-statement, printf

I had knowledge about java so I  tried writing an if block within the for block saying,

```py
for i in range(25):
    if i == 9:
        i = 18
    print(i)
```

This code logic works in java but not in python. What should I do?

Comment: `for i in range(25)` generates a value `i` which range from 0 to 24 included. It cannot be modified, it changes each time. So prefer using a `while` loop and init the variable from outside.

Comment: "I have added brackets to make it legible" don't do that... **write actual Python code as formatted text**. In any case, this *doesn't* work in Java either, because Python for-loops are equivalent to java for-each loops (i.e. enhanced for loops, aka iterator-based loops). If you want the same thing as the C-like java for-loop, you have to use a `while` loop in Python if you want to translate it directly. But you should be using Python-based constructs, don't just tranliterate code from java to python

Comment: @KishanSingh here are some tutorials about: [for loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp) and [while loop](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp) if you want to check the syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A better way to print the above sequence is through a while loop：

```
max_num = 25
i = 1
while i < max_num:
    if i == 9:
        print(18)
        i == 19
    else:
        print(i)
        i += 1
```

Comment: Be careful not to use variable names already defined by Python. In this case you can't use Python `max()` method after, because you defined it to 25. You should rename it into `max_` for example.

Answer (score 7):

Use two ranges and the power of [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html).

```
import itertools

for i in itertools.chain(range(1, 9), range(18,25)):
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a while loop instead worked

```
i = 1
while i < 25:
    if i == 9:
        i += 9
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Output

```py
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
```

Comment: yeah this is correct but  what if I want to print 19 after 8, I will have to change the logic isn't it but I want some random number. like in java I will have to just write i=n, where n is the random number, I don't know if I'm making myself clear. Your answer is absolutely correct but I want some random solution, not associated to a particular question. I hope U are understanding. Thanks for the reply anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use two loops

```py
for i in range(1, 9):
    print(i)
    
    
for i in range(18,25):
    print(i)
```